# get list item versions in linq to sharepoint

Tags: linq, spmetal

How can i access last approved list-items in linq to sharepoint.
Actually I want equivalent of this statement in linq to sharepoint
    if (item.Versions[index].Level == SPFileLevel.Published)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below, its not the actual code for your scenario, its just to get an idea for your requirement.

```
var posts = new List<Post>();
posts =
(from post in
contextSwitch.GetContext(webUrl).Posts
where post.PublicationLevel == 
SPFileLevel.Published
select post).Take(limit).ToList();
```

Where,
PublicationLevel is as follows,

```
var item = (SPListItem)listItem;
PublicationLevel = item.Level;

Check the below source link for more details.
```

[Source](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/10/01/linq-to-sharepoint-obscure-workarounds/)